# Best SEO-friendly practice of adding filters to URLs

Tags: seo, url, url-parameters

I like to know the best approach of adding filters to a URL.

Ex: 1

```
http://example.com/items-recent-1.html
http://example.com/items-price-1.html
```

Above URL is made of site URL / file name / filter by recent or price / page ID.

Ex: 2

```
http://example.com/items-1.html?sortby= recent
http://example.com/items-1.html?sortby= price
```

This URL is made of of site URL / file name / page ID  ? sortby=  filter by recent or price.

Which is the best SEO friendly way of doing this from above examples? Or is there a better way?

Comment: We get these questions from time to time. We had one similar to this just a couple of weeks ago. I would chose option one (of the two) personally, however, I would prefer /recent/ or /price/ which has much more value. For search, the path has more value than a file name which has more value than a parameter. Think left to right when applying value to a URL. Leftward has more value and less the further you move to the right. There are four parts, domain name, path, file name, parameters. Think in terms of these four parts with a preference on the path. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Which one you use doesn't make a huge difference to SEO at all. Semantically speaking as the content remains much the same and the order of the records shown is all that changes then it would be better to put the sort in as a parameter but whether you do it as a rewritten URL path instead won't affect SEO. The thing to remember is that `http://example.com/items-recent-1.html` and `http://example.com/items-price-1.html` to Google will show up as two completely different pages and so will be ranked differently and separately but...
`http://example.com/items-1.html`
`http://example.com/items-1.html?sortby= recent`
`http://example.com/items-1.html?sortby= price`

will all show to Google as the same page and so will be grouped together and Google will decide which one is the most appropriate to return to the end user based on the query.